# Determine if ArcSDE service or direct connect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

Does anybody knows if there is the ability to check a layers datasource, if it is an direct connect to a database or if an ArcSDE service is used?

For both the `esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory` is used. Maybe there is a interface?

Comment: There's two issues here: 1) Why does it matter? 2) Application service connections are deprecated, so all connections will eventually be direct. The connection type is not a property, so that means extracting the connection properties and parsing the instance parameter.

Comment: The only time I need to know this is when issuing log statements in my code--it can really speed up troubleshooting down the line (especially when clients have the option of connecting with either option).  Admittedly,it's probably been 5+ years since I've coded for one of these environments.

Comment: We need this information because we want to publish data from a geodatabase in oracle via UMN Mapserver. In time the Mapserver only can show data from such a geodatabase served in an ArcSDE-Layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Vince mentioned in his comment, you have to parse the connection properties.

A quick google search on: `IsDirectConnect` and `filetype:cs`
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=IsDirectConnect+filetype%3Acs&es_th=1 reveals an example that you can build on:
ftp://ftp.leesburgflorida.gov/gis/Telvent/Custom%20Code/Leesburg_10.1/Miner/Miner.ATeam/WorkspaceHelper.cs

```
public static bool IsDirectConnect(string instance)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(instance.ToString().ToLower(),
                     @"^sde:(oracle(8|9)i|sqlserver:\w+|db2)$",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                        | RegexOptions.Singleline
                        | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                        | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

}
```

Obviously, you would update this with current rdbms versions (and maybe add postgres if that's what you are using).  It's a typical approach.

Comment: Matching "^sde:" is enough (and then you're not RDBMS dependent).